# Expand and collapse, with a link for an anchor as target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to use jQuery and jQuery Collapse to build out a list of options of links where a link can be expanded or collapsed on a first click, and if it's expanded, on a second click the link will take you to the destined href.

I started a jsfiddle to solve my problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/smittles/vtuLsh7s/

```
<div class="expandy" data-collapse>
    <div class="title"><a href="http://google.com">Google!</a></div> 
    <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum Cupidatat esse tempor reprehenderit ea sint occaecat sint Excepteur commodo esse exercitation.
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the anchor tag gets wrapped by an anchor tag with an href="#" by jQuery Collapse.

How can I build a collapsible structure like this where the anchor tag becomes "linkable" if the panel is expanded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simpler:

javascript code:

```
$("#divId").click(function () {
    $('#divId').unbind("click");
    $("#divId").click(function () {
        window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
    });
});
```

Comment: Since it is one link, I don't see much of a problem

Comment: I put an Id in the div for that ;)

Comment: That's the reason o believe the solution scales nicely. I'm targeting an specific div. If you have more divs you simply reuse a function and call it many times

Comment: The question requires the link to be clicable after the collapser is open. That's what this code does.

Comment: For that one only need to iterate through the colapsable  divs and call my method. This is not that much code.

Comment: Come on. You know that is not true. Don't push it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the URL will be passed through a PHP variable in a foreach loop, meaning I won't have access to it from inside the javascript.

Comment: Tonight I'll refactor it tonight ok :)?

Answer (score 0):

No need for the overhead of jQuery on this one. It is actually pretty easy to do this with vanilla javascript.

Basically we assign a click handler to the link which is in the title of each expandy.

In the click handler we check to see whether the expandy is open or not.

If not we prevent the browser from redirecting, if so we allow the user to redirect

Either way we toggle the collapse / expand

No need for any external libraries at all.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/x4ga0pgm/2/))

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('expandy'), section;
    for(var i = 0; section = sections[i]; i++) {
        section.querySelector('.title a').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
            var section = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
            if(section.style.height == '1em') e.preventDefault();
            section.style.height = section.style.height == '1em' ? 'auto' : '1em';
        },false);
    }
})();
```

Comment: This solution doesn't activate the anchor once opened. Once expanded, I want to be able to click the anchor and navigate to google.com

Answer (score 0):

I changed the html a bit like this:

```
<div class="expandy" data-collapse>
    <a id='test' href="http://google.com">
      <div class="title">Google!</div> 
    </a>
    <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum Cupidatat esse tempor reprehenderit ea sint occaecat sint Excepteur commodo esse exercitation.
    </div>
</div>
```

and added this JS to fix your problem:

```
$('#test').click( function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('open'))
    {
       window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    }
});
```